# How to draw a smooth curve between user touched points?

Tags: java, android, canvas, curve, smoothing

I'm developing a game. User draws a curve on a screen by finger, then I get user touch points.

I want to draw a curve between these points. They scattered and when i use canvas and draw lines between them the result isn't a smooth curve.

I am searching for some way to draw a smooth curve through these points (maybe by modifying or removing some of the points that aren't in same trend as others).

Can anyone help me?

here I add a [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ss15q.jpg) to show what i mean

Comment: [Bézier curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve). Look it up, plenty of resources available. To move or remove points that "don't fit" is a science on its own, requiring quite a bit of statistical analysis on the points... That is possibly not worth the trouble at this stage.

Comment: @ppeterka Thank you,but it doesn't help me,my game need to draw the exactly user touch path.

Comment: Learn about [splines](https://www.particleincell.com/2012/bezier-splines/) which uses a set of Bezier curves to connect a set of points. If you are starting with so many points that your curves are jagged, then you could sacrifice a few points and apply a [path simplification algorithm](http://mourner.github.io/simplify-js/).

Comment: @markE thanks,I see links,but I'm very confused!can you help me more?maybe by some code in android or what else.

Comment: Link to image not working. Removed.

Comment: @Michael_B OK thanks

Answer (score 0):

As I learned from Adobe Photoshop and Illustrator, the more points you add, the more jagged the image will look. When drawing, you could skip every other point or something. This may provide inaccurate drawings if the user moves rapidly, so you could check if the skipped point is close or far.

```
final int len = pointsX.length, far = 50;
for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
{
    if (i % 2 == 0)  //If even, draw
    {
        //Draw code
    }
    else if (Math.abs(pointsX[i] - pointsX[i-1]) > far || Math.abs(pointsY[i] - pointsY[i-1]) > far)
    {   //If the index is odd, check if the distance from the current to the last point is far.
        //If it is far, draw. If not far, skip the draw, so it doesn't appear as jagged.
        //Draw code
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you,I had same idea in past,that skip one point of each two,and it didn't have a good result.But the idea of check distance of two point and then determine skipp or not,seems to be a good idea.I will try it later and inform the result.maybe it's good to use this approach beside of the other solutions:) thanks again.(and sorry for bad english)

Comment: Oh no,it doesn't help.I really need modify jagged points,b ut thanks anyway